# Can we use http code 422(Unprocessable Entity) for Get operations?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, http

Team - We are using `422 HTTP Status Code for validations` in our code for `HTTP GET` operations. But not sure, whether we can use get operations. As `422 unprocessable` entity sounds more like request body validation - Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Normally GET request doesn't have Payload. We use the GET to retrieve the data from Server/DB which are already verified at the time of creation or insert. which means we don't need to validate data when retrieving.

If we have Payload we should use POST. We can use 422 or 400 with POST according to requirement.

**GET**

> The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an
> entity) is identified by the Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to
> a data-producing process, it is the produced data which shall be
> returned as the entity in the response and not the source text of the
> process, unless that text happens to be the output of the process.

**POST**

> The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the
> entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource
> identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line. POST is designed to
> allow a uniform method to cover the following functions:
>
> ```
>   - Annotation of existing resources;
>   - Posting a message to a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list,
>     or similar group of articles;
>   - Providing a block of data, such as the result of submitting a
>     form, to a data-handling process;
>   - Extending a database through an append operation.
> ```

[400](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-26#section-6.5.1)

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
> will not process the request due to something which is perceived to
> be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
> message framing, or deceptive request routing).

[422](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2)

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.You will not find 422 in RFC 723x

[Source RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3) [Source RFC 723x](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231)

Comment: @Romil -We are accepting headers and query parameters-per our requirement,we are validating headers and query parameters -So we need to throw constraints-felt 422 status code is not suitable-so wanted to check-thanks

Comment: 2616 is outdated. Please refer to the 723x RFCs.

Comment: @EricStein Thanks for your comment, I have added it

Answer (score 0):

> 422 "Unprocessable Entity" is more about semantic error, The URI is
>   not part of the request entity, therefore 422 does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

The description of 422 says,

The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions.

Instead I think 400 code more suits here.

So it might have been argued that it was inappropriate for semantic errors. But not any more; since June 2014 the relevant standard RFC 7231, which supersedes the previous RFC2616, gives the use of 400 (Bad Request) more broadly as
the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error

Answer (score -2):

422 Unprocessable entity can be used for any type of requests. It is not specific to GET or POST or DDELETE. If you have to validate any data that can be accepted as request and any pre-conditions have to be validated, HTTP 422 can be thrown.

Eg. There is path param in GET call something as age you are passing which is syntactically correct say 16 but your business logic for age above 18. Hence throwing a 400 here is not correct.

Reference: https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Comment: 422 is about the *payload*. GET in general doesn't have a payload.